# Validator not working on first start of the server, works after project reload

Tags: jsf, validation

a very strange problem is occuring to me:
On the first Start of my JSF-Project on a Tomcat 7.0 Server the validator for the username is not working. If i reload the Project, everything suddenly works like a charm. Strangely, the registerUser method works always.

Here are my code snippets:

```
        <h:outputLabel value="Username:" for="username"></h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText id="username" value="#{register.name}" validator="# {register.validateName}" validatorMessage="Suggestion: Try another name">
        <h:message for="username"></h:message></h:inputText>
```

Next My register.java bean:

```
package fileserver;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage; 
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Register {

public String name;
public String passWord;
public String queryString;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getPassWord() {
    return passWord;
}


public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
    this.passWord = passWord;
}


public String registerUser() throws SQLException{


        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.println("Damn");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/JavaServerFaces", "postgres",
        "123456");
        System.out.println("Connection success");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

        }

    queryString= "INSERT INTO tbl_benutzer"
                + "( username, password)"
         + "VALUES ('"+ name+"', '"+ passWord+"')";
        Statement sql = connection.createStatement();

        if (connection != null) {
        sql.execute(queryString);
        System.out.println("Successfully added:VALUES ('"+name+"', '"+ passWord+"')");
        sql.close();
        connection.close();
        return "/index.xhtml";
        }
        //is here because the method requires a return value
        return null;
        }


public void validateName(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
        throws ValidatorException, SQLException {
    System.out.println(context.toString());
    queryString = "SELECT username FROM tbl_benutzer WHERE username='"+ name +"'";

    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        System.out.println("Shit");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/JavaServerFaces", "postgres",
    "123456");
    System.out.println("Connection success");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Statement names=connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet Nameset=names.executeQuery(queryString);

    if(Nameset.next()){
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        message.setSummary("Name is already used.");
        message.setDetail("Name is already used.");
        context.addMessage("userForm:register", message);   
        throw new ValidatorException(message);

    }

}       
}
```

After some research i found out, that String name is null in the validator for some unknown reason and i can't get it filled, even if i directly call getName() in this method.
Does anyone have a Solution for this?

Comment: Is `validator="# {register.validateName}"` an exact copypaste from your code? Including that space between `#` and `{`? There's by the way a serious SQL injection hole in this code. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: This is just a project for college. The main focus is on the Server, not the database, I know about the hole, but the way I access the database is not that important. Also the blank between the # and the { is a copy/paste error

Comment: Also I just found the main issue seems to be that name is null when the validator is called. There seems to be a problem at the point in time when the validator is called. Can i somehow delay this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the SQL injection holes and many(!!) other design errors, the following is flawed:

```
public void validateName(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException, SQLException {
    queryString = "SELECT username FROM tbl_benutzer WHERE username='"+ name +"'";
    // ...
```

You're not working with the submitted value which is available as 3rd argument `value`. You're directly using the model value `name` while that's not yet updated at the point the validator is invoked. Basically, you're working with the initial value instead of the submitted value. That also explains why it only "works" after submitting the form for the second time.

Fix it accordingly:

```
public void validateName(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException, SQLException {
    queryString = "SELECT username FROM tbl_benutzer WHERE username='"+ value +"'";
    // ...
```

Once again, there are way too many design errors in the code. I really hope that your tutor knows what he's doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After I read this I instantly facepalmed. Works perfectly as I want now. Stuuuuuupid mistake by me. I believe my tutor knows what he's doing, but he usually likes working code over perfectly clean code. Also I'm not the most talented programmer (Actually I am pretty amazed that I got this far without asking for help). Anyway thanks again :)